# Stopping JPopupMenu stealing the focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpopupmenu

I have a `JTextField` for which I'm hoping to suggest results to match the user's input. I'm displaying these suggestions in a `JList` contained within a `JPopupMenu`.

**However**, when opening the popup menu programmatically via [`show(Component invoker, int x, int y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int%29), the focus is getting taken from the `JTextField`.

Strangely enough, if I call `setVisible(true)` instead, the focus is not stolen; but then the `JPopupMenu` is not attached to any panel, and when minimizing the application whilst the box is open, it stays painted on the window.

I've also tried to reset the focus to the `JTextField` using `requestFocus()`, but then I have to restore the caret position using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, and the *invoke later* side of things is giving the user a slight margin to mess around with the existing contents / overwrite it / or do other unpredictable things.

The code I've got is effectively:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();

field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        JList list = getAListOfResults();

        menu.add(list);
        menu.show(field, 0, field.getHeight());
    }
});
```

Can anyone suggest the best avenue to go down to show the `JPopupMenu` programmatically whilst preserving the focus on the `JTextField`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The technical answer is to set the popup's focusable property to false:

```
popup.setFocusable(false);
```

The implication is that the textField has to take over all keyboard and mouse-triggered actions that are normally handled by the list itself, sosmething like:

```
final JList list = new JList(Locale.getAvailableLocales());
final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.add(new JScrollPane(list));
popup.setFocusable(false);
final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
Action down = new AbstractAction("nextElement") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       int next = Math.min(list.getSelectedIndex() + 1,
               list.getModel().getSize() - 1);
       list.setSelectedIndex(next);
       list.ensureIndexIsVisible(next);
    }
};
field.getActionMap().put("nextElement", down);
field.getInputMap().put(
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "nextElement");
```

As your context is very similar to a JComboBox, you might consider having a look into the sources of BasicComboBoxUI and BasicComboPopup.

**Edit**

Just for fun, the following *is not* answering the focus question :-) Instead, it demonstrates how to use a sortable/filterable JXList to show only the options in the dropdown which correspond to the typed text (here with a starts-with rule)

```
// instantiate a sortable JXList
final JXList list = new JXList(Locale.getAvailableLocales(), true);
list.setSortOrder(SortOrder.ASCENDING);

final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.add(new JScrollPane(list));
popup.setFocusable(false);
final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);

// instantiate a PatternModel to map text --> pattern 
final PatternModel model = new PatternModel();
model.setMatchRule(PatternModel.MATCH_RULE_STARTSWITH);
// listener which to update the list's RowFilter on changes to the model's pattern property  
PropertyChangeListener modelListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("pattern".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            updateFilter((Pattern) evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }

    private void updateFilter(Pattern newValue) {
        RowFilter<Object, Integer> filter = null;
        if (newValue != null) {
            filter = RowFilters.regexFilter(newValue);
        }
        list.setRowFilter(filter);
    }
};
model.addPropertyChangeListener(modelListener);

// DocumentListener to update the model's rawtext property on changes to the field
DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateAfterDocumentChange();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateAfterDocumentChange();
    }

    private void updateAfterDocumentChange() {
        if (!popup.isVisible()) {
            popup.show(field, 0, field.getHeight());
        } 
        model.setRawText(field.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
};
field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
```

Comment: After a lot of googling, this answer helped me alot

Answer (score 2):

It looks straight forward to me. Add the following

`field.requestFocus();`

after

```
 menu.add(list);
 menu.show(field, 0, field.getHeight());
```

Of course, you will have to code for when to hide the popup etc based on what is going on with the `JTextField`.

i.e;

```
 menu.show(field, field.getX(), field.getY()+field.getHeight());
 menu.setVisible(true);
 field.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; unfortunately I've already tried this approach. It gets more complicated as I then have to restore the caret position using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, and the *invoke later* side of things gives the user a slight margin to mess around with the existing contents / overwrite it / or do other unpredictable things.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look to JXSearchField, which is part of [xswingx](http://code.google.com/p/xswingx/)